# SwiftUI - Clipping a large image when view has no width

Tags: swiftui

I have a tappable card that clips an image without a frame width. When the image is large the clipping doesn't seem to work. With regular size class I want as many of these cards that I can fit on each row. In these screenshots you can see the cards with the large image are consuming loads of space and the text is not shown, while the smaller image (candy) is working fine. I won't know the size of the images. These are jpeg's. All of the examples I've seen including Apple doc's show simple cases with a frame width. I would appreciate any suggestions?
[image: Image 1 portrait]

[image: Image 2 landscape]

[image: NewIn_MenuCampaign_5]

**Code**

```
public var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            {}
        }, label: {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "NewIn_MenuCampaign_5"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(height: mediaHeight)
                    .clipped()
                HStack(spacing: Spacing.space2) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        if let title = data.title {
                            Text(title, fontType: .textL)
                        }
                        if let content = data.content {
                            Text(content, fontType: .textLRegular)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    IconImage(asset: .arrowRight)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                }
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 0)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 8)
            }
            .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 8)
            .padding(.bottom, 4)
        }
}
```

Comment: I've added more code and the large image file. Place a few of these inside parent view and then inside a scrollView and a lazyVGrid. The padding leading/trailing for scrollview should be 16. We have it as part of a viewModifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use the image as an overlay of something that you know the size and ratio (like a placeholder):

```
Color.gray //  Placeholder
    .overlay {
        Image(.newInMenuCampaign5)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    }
    .clipped()
    .frame(height: mediaHeight)
```

[image: Demo]

[Here is fully working code](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/2f135081efc5c65ab7f6e7a8c68687c2)

Answer (score 1):

In the end this code is working for me. Thanks for your help Mojtaba

```
VStack {
            Color.clear
                .overlay(
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mn3", ofType: ".jpg")!)!)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                )
                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                .frame(height: 143)
            Text("title")
            Text("subtitle")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you repost my answer instead of accepting it?

Comment: this is not the same as the other answer post. it's perfectly acceptable for askers to adapt code from other answers and post what worked best for them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156239/997587, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388037/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262210/11107541, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107001/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229196/997587, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305906/11107541